# Here is a question for Android Splash Screen implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01"

Tags: android, splash-screen

We need to designed for identify whether the user login or not？It means that We need to designed a routes to decide which Activity we need to display after the splash screen. How we can write code for that. As we write a SplashActivity as a routes, it will has white screen and become slower than other apps. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer for your question in the official documentation. Please, take a look https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate

It can be implemented in the following way:

```
//let's imagine this is your SplashScreen, the starting point of the app
 class RoutingActivity : Activity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Keep the splash screen visible for this Activity
    // it means that there will be only your splash screen visible
    // since we don't set "setContentView(resId : Int)"
    splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
    
    //after you've checked if user is logged in, show the other activity  
    startSomeNextActivity()
    finish()
 }
```

...